# Slide in text using CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's my code:

JS

```
var object = ["your company", "email marketing", "your company"];
var mediaName = ["FB", "Tw", "FB"];
var action = ["say thanks", 'retweet it', 'like it'];
var index = 0;

function iterate() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        switchText();
    }, 2500);
}

function switchText() {
    document.querySelector('span.object').innerHTML = object[index];
    document.querySelector('span.medium').innerHTML = mediaName[index];
    document.querySelector('span.action').innerHTML = action[index];
    index++;
    if (index % 3 === 0) index = 0;
    iterate();
}
iterate();
```

CSS

```
body {
background: orange;
}
span {
background: #FFF;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 2px;
color: orange;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML

```
If someone mentions <span class="object"></span> on <span class="medium"></span> then <span `class="action"></span>
```

2 things i'm stuck on:

1/  I'm trying to slide in the text like on http://www.mailerloop.com/

2/  I want the first sentence to load with the page, not appear a couple of seconds later

Here's my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/EdMN9/5/

Thanks :)

Comment: 2nd issue .. http://jsfiddle.net/Zr2j2/

Comment: great, any idea on the sliding text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second point is very easy to achieve: Just write the first sentence there, and you don't have to wait for loading:

```
<p>If someone mentions <span class="object">your company</span> on <span class="medium">FB</span> then <span class="action">say thanks</span>
```

This way is already there and no wait will be shown.

The first point... If you want implement it with pure javascript, you should look for a snippet of code able of doing it. I personally use jQuery, because is much more easy to achieve it.

#### UPDATE

Ok, if no pure js is needed, you could use this:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/

A fiddle is here to show you it working: http://jsfiddle.net/EdMN9/13/

You just have to hide the element with the slide, change it, and then, show it again. A bit more of CSS is needed, I added to the span classes the no-wrap to avoid it take two lines, but you'll have to avoid the paragraph "go down" (check the fiddle)

Comment: Doesnt have to be pure JS

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this is an optimal solution. But you can call switchText(); before iterate() once to get the solution like that.

```
var object = [ "your company", "email marketing", "your company"];
var mediaName = ["FB", "Tw", "FB"];
var action = [ "say thanks", 'retweet it', 'like it' ];
var index = 0;
switchText();
function iterate() {  
    setTimeout(function() {
        switchText();
    }, 2500);
}
```